# creating a 2px thick backline as a connector of the menu items

Tags: html, css

everyone!
I'm having a problem with this menu-bar design. First look at my design. Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hLtat/embedded/result/ . As you see, there is a 2px thick, Green back line behind the menubar. I want this line to occupy the full width of the screen. How can I get this green backline as a 100% width filled? 
Here is my current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Flat Nav</title>

<style type="text/css" media="screen">

a:before, a:after{
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute; right: 0; top:60px;
    z-index: -1;
}
nav{

    text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
    display: inline-block; list-style: none; position: relative;
}
    nav ul li {
        float: left; margin: 0 20px 0 0;
    }
        nav ul li a {
            display: block; width: 120px; height: 120px; opacity: 0.9;
        }
            nav ul li:nth-child(1) a {
                background-color: #5bb2fc;
            }
            nav ul li:nth-child(2) a {
                background-color: #58ebd3;
            }
            nav ul li:nth-child(3) a {
                background-color: #ffa659;
            }
            nav ul li:nth-child(4) a {
                background-color: #ff7a85;
            }

                nav ul li a span {
                    font: 20px "Dosis", sans-serif; text-transform: uppercase; 
                    display: none;
                }
                    nav ul li a:hover span {
                        display: block;
                    }

                nav ul li:nth-child(1) a span {
                    color: #5bb2fc;
                    position: absolute; left: 70px; top: 130px;
                }
                nav ul li:nth-child(2) a span {
                    color: #58ebd3;
                    position: absolute; left: 200px; top: 130px;
                }
                nav ul li:nth-child(3) a span {
                    color: #ffa659;
                    position: absolute; left: 320px; top: 130px;
                }
                nav ul li:nth-child(4) a span {
                    color: #ff7a85;
                    position: absolute; left: 470px; top: 130px;
                }
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="demo">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <span>Home</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <span>About</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <span>Portfolio</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <span>Contact</span>
                </a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `:before` and `:after` pseudo on `a`, use it on `#demo` instead, also make sure you use `position: relative;` on the `#demo` element.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hLtat/1/)

```
div#demo {
    position: relative;
}

div#demo:after {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%; /* 50% from the top */
    z-index: -1;
    margin-top: -1px; /* 1/2 of the total width of the virtual element */
}
```

Though, here's a catch, if you are looking to do something like this with a responsive design, than the line behind the element won't behave as it used to behave in your demonstration, so make sure you are good with this before implementing it, or use `@media` queries to change the behavior...

Comment: Ohh Thanks for Asking about me MR Alien, I had some work in my office..so i was not regular present in this Stack College :)

Comment: @Deekey Oh, kwel, njoy :) lets clean up the comments, and btw thanks for saying cool ;)

Comment: Thank you very much Mr.Alien. You are absolutely right. I liked the approach.

Comment: Is there any problm if I use :after on 'nav' instead of #demo ?

Comment: @user3164311 nope, you can use it

Answer (score 4):

Replace this code..

```
a:before, a:after{
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute; right: 0; top:60px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

with this:

```
nav:before, nav:after{
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute; right: 0; top:80px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But with the change of the height of 'a', the backline doesn't remain in center.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution.

add the following html mark-up before your `nav`.

```
<div class="line"></div>
```

css

```
.line{
    position:absolute;
    background-color:green;
    height:2px;
    width:100%;
    top:80px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this demo, just put a div line behind the buttons
http://jsfiddle.net/hLtat/9/embedded/result

```
    #backline{
    background:green;
    height:2px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative; top:70px;z-index:-1;
    }
```

Update: I've changed the css a bit to make the elements centered:
http://jsfiddle.net/hLtat/10/embedded/result

Changes in the css:

```
nav{
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
display: inline-block; list-style: none
}
```

Note that i also change the  position attribute to "relative" so that the text in  are positioned relatively to their parent  elements.

Comment: But the elements aren't in center.